# Which activity method is called first?

Tags: android, android-activity

Which activity method is called first in Android? For example `viewWillAppear` is called first in case of IPhone.
Also can someone tell me when I come back from an activity to previous activity, which method is called first? I don't want to load everything again and again each time I come back to an activity.

Thanks,
Stone

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you enter your app, the life cycle flow will be like this:

**onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume()**

Now if you are using an intent to move from your current Activity to the next Activity, these are the methods of the current activity that will be executed:

**onPause() -> onStop()**

When you come back to the same activity(e.g., using back key event), these are the methods of the current activity that will be executed:

**onStart() -> onResume()**

And when you exit your app, the flow goes like this:

**onPause() -> onStop() -> onDestroy()**

Answer (score 2):

All the information you need is provided in the documentation on [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). You should read it as it is important to understand. Incidentally, viewWillAppear is not called first on the iPhone. There are a couple methods called before that.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you are new to android. here is a link which describes about the life cycle of an activity. [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

in short **onCreate** is called first and when you comeback from an activity **onResume** will be called. **onResume** will also be called the first time as well. **onPause** will be called whenever an activity goes background.

Answer (score 1):

if the prevoius Activity has been killed by OS when its gone background then again `onCreate()` method is called. or else its `onResume()` method which gets called..